# How to use require() in javascript to access a javascript library on the web

Tags: javascript, commonjs

I'm really new to coding from scratch in javascript (I have used js before but on systems that already have includes, etc abstracted away), and I'm trying to use the tumblr API.

It took me hours to even figure out how to be able to use the "require" statement, which wasn't clear at all. No guides say how to get require working in the browser, they all just assume that you can use that keyword. Finally, I found a link and currently I am achieving the use of 'require' by linking to

```
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/Localnet/CommonScript/master/lib/modules.js"</script>
```

But getting to my main question: what I want is to be able to reference tumblr.js from the github repository. I'm linking to the script, same as above

```
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/tumblr/tumblr.js/master/index.js"</script>
```

And then later I'm trying to do this:

```
var tumblr = require('tumblr.js')
```

But when I use require there it tries to look in a subdirectory of my webpage, not what I linked to at the top. How do I reference that code?

I know this is a beginner's question, but I haven't been able to find a decent answer anywhere. Any clarification would help immensely.

Comment: What you are trying to include is a node.js module. It cannot be used for browser.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the concept of javascript outside the browser. I thought javascript could only be used in a browser?

Comment: JavaScript is a dynamic language. Browsers pioneered its use, making it the web language. Different browsers have different JS engines like firefox uses spidermonkey and chrome uses v8. These engines can be embedded in a server application having extra API, for eg node.js is based on V8.

Answer (score 1):

`require` is for server-side JavaScript. Simply including the `<script>` tag is the correct way to include a script in an HTML document.

Comment: But if I just use the script tag, can I access variables defined in the script that was included at the top of the page in a later script? It seems like I can't do that, it tells me variables in the included script are undefined.